# Get Data From Multiple Tables On the Basis of Column Value From Different Table

Tags: mysql

I have one Table of users in which their is LOGIN_ID, LOGIN_PASSWORD, and USER_ROLE.

I want to get Name of USERS From Different Table with single query.

e.g.

- Login_ID: 1001 is from students so we have to get the name form students.
- Login_ID: 235738932 is from Employees so we have to get name from Employees.

There is no Foreign Key Relation in users Tables because Login_id is from two different Tables.

Comment: What query did you try? and where did it stop because of what problem?

Comment: I do not think it is smart to store the name of a student in the `student` table, and the name of an employee in the `employee` table. Think of what happens if a student becomes an employee.  After that you will have the name in two tables for the same person. It should be simpler to store the name of a user only in the table users.

Comment: students have messID and Employees have CNIC so their is No Issue. But it is considered as Login_id in users Table so we require Conditional name if Login_id in employee than it should get name from employee if Login_id is in student so it should get name from Employee. in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT
   LOGIN_ID, 
   LOGIN_PASSWORD,
   USER_ROLE,
   CONCAT(COALESCE(students.name,''),COALESCE(employee.name,'')) as Name
FROM users
LEFT JOIN students ON students.Login_ID = users.Login_ID
LEFT JOIN employee ON employee.Login_ID = users.Login_ID
```

`COALESCE(students.name,'')` Will return the students name. If the name is not found, the values will be NULL, and COALESCE will change this to ''.

The same happend to the name of the employee. Both names are getting concatenated.